# Design Preview mode is not working with Label type DataWindow

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I am new to PowerBuilder.

I am trying to use Design Preview functionality to change attribute of column at run time. It is working fine for free form DataWindow but when I tried to use same feature with Label type DataWindow then only X and Y attribute for column are not updating while moving column.

Sequence >> Select column and make column as movable and then try to move column by drag. It is not updating X and Y position and all other attribute are updating properly.

Can any one tell me why it is not working with Label type DataWindow or what is the other way to do it ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Not sure to understand. Maybe you are confusing some concepts. Design preview is at design time and you are talking of runtime. Please post what you have, what you expect and the expressions you are using if any.

Comment: Hello Seki, It is possible to move column and change attribute at run time and you can store data window source in database and at the time of retrieve you can retrieve from edited source which we have stored.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the "Label" datawindow object via the datawindow painter.
2. Select any column you want to be moveable.
3. With the column highlighed select the "Position" tab.
4. Check the "Moveable" checkbox on the Position tab.
5. Open datawindow object in preview mode.
6. Move the column (via drag) in the design section (top) OR the preview section (bottom) of the datawindow painter.

You should be able to move the column at runtime as well if the datawindow control is in print preview mode.  I verified this works using PB12.5 Classic.  HTH